# Is it possible to dispatch events after every 30 minutes in flurry analytics as similar to Google analytucs?

Tags: android, flurry-analytics

Like google analytics has setSessionimeout where all the vents are grouped together and at the end events are dispatched.Is there anything similar for Flurry analytics,As flurry hits the flurry server instantly,I want it to bunch together all the events in a session (Suppose of 30 min ) and then disptach them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to force the Flurry SDK to report analytics session data at specified time. A Flurry session is defined by

"If the app pauses or moves to the background for more than 10 seconds, the next time the app runs, Flurry agent will automatically create a new session and end the previous session. Otherwise, Flurry agent will continue the same session. This can be updated via the setSessionContinueSeconds method. If the app is terminated, a new session will be created when the app runs again."

The only way to control the session reporting is through the app lifecycle. But generally I would expect all of the events to be reported in a single batch per session. You can observe this behavior by watching the event log in the Flurry UI as the app is closed and/or reopened.

setSessionContinueSeconds is really only useful for cases where you would want the Flurry session to continue for longer than 10 seconds while the app is in the background. For instance an app that plays music in the background.